# How can I create a list of refs in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having some trouble creating a list of refs for a list of elements that I'm rendering into a component, I've tried several solutions from similar answer but nothing seems to work, here's what I'm trying to accomplish (though my code is probably wrong as refs are staying null).

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
    const refs = useRef(Array(data.length).fill(null));

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                data.map((data, index) => (
                    <li key={index} ref={(element) => {
                        refs[index] = element;
                    }}>{data}</li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    );
};
```

Atm the refs are staying null, none of them are getting assigned, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to have a reference to the elements for? Usually (but not always) refs aren't actually needed (and are better avoided)

Comment: @CertainPerformance This li's are in reality columns of a table that I'm trying to resize (the original library is react-virtualized and doesn't have this option) and I need to compute their initial width (as it is automatic so that react-virtualized makes them all the same width) to then be able to either increase or decrease their width with a handler (for which I'm using react-draggable.

Comment: [this](https://eliaslog.pw/how-to-add-multiple-refs-to-one-useref-hook/) should help you with what you requirements are

Answer (score 1):

can you please change `refs[index] = element` to `refs.current[index] = element`, as you can see the below code.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
    const refs = useRef(Array(data.length).fill(null));

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                data.map((data, index) => (
                    <li key={index} ref={(element) => {
                        refs.current[index] = element;
                    }}>{data}</li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    );
};
```

Comment: I did that but it still seems to stay undefined (I replaced `useRef(Array(data.length).fill(null)` for `useRef([])`)

Comment: I've just tried going back to the `useRef(Array(data.length).fill(null)` but in this case it stays null